# ¿porque la funcion glutIdleFunc consume el 100% del procesador?

Tags: c++, opengl

La función `glutIdleFunc` consume el 100% del procesador, pero la necesito para actualizar la ventana a **30fps**.

He visto un ejemplo donde la utiliza pero no tiene este problema (ejemplo en: http://opengl-esp.superforo.net/t58-juego-snake)

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void rectangulo(int x, int y, int ancho, int alto, float rojo, float verde, float azul)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(rojo, verde, azul);
    glVertex2f(x,y);
    glVertex2f(x, y+alto);
    glVertex2f(x+ancho, y+alto);
    glVertex2f(x+ancho, y);
    glEnd();
}

void inicializar_ventana()
{
    glClearColor(0.5,1,1, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0, 880, 0, 495);//Izquierda Derecha Arriba Abajo

    //Quiero el origen arriba a la izquierda
    glRotatef(180, 1, 0, 0);
    glTranslatef(0, -495, 0);

}

void dibujar_ventana()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    rectangulo(10, 10, 100, 100, 1, 0, 0);
    rectangulo(200, 10, 100, 100, 0, 1, 0);
    rectangulo(10, 200, 100, 100, 0, 0, 1);
    rectangulo(200, 200, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1);

    glFlush();
    //glutSwapBuffers();
}

void actualizar(int valor)
{
    //Calculos
    glutTimerFunc(33.3333,actualizar,1);
}

int main(int numero_argumentos, char* argumentos[])
{
    glutInit(&numero_argumentos, argumentos);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(880, 495);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("Ejemplo");

    inicializar_ventana();
    glutDisplayFunc(dibujar_ventana);
    glutTimerFunc(33.3333, actualizar, 1);
    glutIdleFunc(dibujar_ventana);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Se puede compilar con: (en `kubuntu` necesita el paquete `freeglut3-dev`)

```
g++ ejemplo.c++ -lGL -lglut -lGLU
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambiar `GLUT_SINGLE` por `GLUT_DOUBLE` y `glFlush()` por `glutSwapBuffers()` resuelve el problema.
Como habían dicho antes `glutIdleFunc` se ejecuta a máxima velocidad por eso utiliza el 100% yo creo que al cambiar a `GLUT_DOUBLE` se limita a 60fps (según las pruebas que he realizado).

Decidí no utilizar la función `glutIdleFunc` porque no puedo controlar los fps, en cambio lo hice con `glutTimerFunc` que no tiene problemas con `GLUT_SINGLE`.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

int i=0;
void rectangulo(int x, int y, int ancho, int alto, float rojo, float verde, float azul)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(rojo, verde, azul);
    glVertex2f(x,y);
    glVertex2f(x, y+alto);
    glVertex2f(x+ancho, y+alto);
    glVertex2f(x+ancho, y);
    glEnd();
}

void inicializar_ventana()
{
    glClearColor(0.5,1,1, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0, 880, 0, 495);//Izquierda Derecha Arriba Abajo

    //Quiero el origen arriba a la izquierda
    glRotatef(180, 1, 0, 0);
    glTranslatef(0, -495, 0);

}

void dibujar_ventana()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    rectangulo( i, 15, 100, 100, 1, 0, 0 );
    rectangulo( 200, i, 100, 100, 0, 1, 0 );
    rectangulo( i, i, 100, 100, 0, 0, 1 );
    rectangulo( 200, 200, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1 );

    glFlush();
    //glutSwapBuffers();
}

void actualizar(int valor)
{
    i++;//Mueve los rectangulos
    dibujar_ventana();
    glutTimerFunc(33.3333,actualizar,1);
}

int main(int numero_argumentos, char* argumentos[])
{
    glutInit(&numero_argumentos, argumentos);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    //glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(880, 495);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Ejemplo");

    inicializar_ventana();
    glutDisplayFunc(dibujar_ventana);
    glutTimerFunc(33.3333, actualizar, 1);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```